# Any reason why my --help info won't print when it's my argv[1]? Any advice is appreciated

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, strcmp

I'm having trouble getting my --help statement to print if the user enters it for argv[1]. Is there any advice that anyone can provide on what I may be doing wrong? I appreciate any help that can be provided.

I have the strcmp function to compare two strings character by character to see if the first argument is --help or something else.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void help_info(char * info);
void numarg_error_message(char * info2);
int strcmp(const char *string, const char *string2);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    char *helping;
    char *helping1;
    int i, c;
    int num_sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < argc ; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", argv[i]);
        //c = atoi(argv[i]);
        //num_sum += c;
    }
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        numarg_error_message(helping1);
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0)
    {
        help_info(helping);
        }

    else
    {
    printf("Hi");
    }

    return 0;
    }

    void help_info(char* help)
    {

    printf("Usage: p2\n\n");

    printf("p2 --help\n");
    printf("\tdisplay thus usage material.\n\n");
    printf("p2 <1> [<0> <1> ...]\n");
    printf("\t calculate the sum, minimum, maximum and mean of the real\n");
    printf("\t number arguments. Non-numeric values will be echoed to\n");
    printf("\t stdout, one per line, with the numeric results printed\n");
    printf("\t following the non-numeric lines.\n\n");

    }

    void numarg_error_message(char *errormessage)
    {
    char *help3;

    printf("Error: not enough arguments.\n");
    help_info(help3);

    }

        int strcmp(const char * str1, const char * str2) //comparing two strings
    {
    const char *cmp1 = str1;
    const char *cmp2 = str2;

    while (*cmp1 == *cmp2)
    {

        cmp1++;
        cmp2++;
    }

    return (*cmp1 - *cmp2);
}
```

The expected output is supposed to be the information in the help_info function when I enter --help as my argv[1]. The output I'm getting is "name of program --help Hi" every time. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: @user3121023 Also, unless the code is compiled as freestanding, having a function with the same name as a standard library function is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Don't implement your own `strcmp`; it's undefined behavior and most likely slower than the one implemented by the standard C library.

That being said, the control condition for your `while` loop inside `strcmp` is wrong. It doesn't stop on the terminating null character at the end of the string.

To fix that, do this:

```
while (*cmp1 && *cmp1 == *cmp2)
```

instead of this:

```
while (*cmp1 == *cmp2)
```

To combat the undefined behavior, you can name your function `compare_string` or something similar (as long as the name doesn't start with `str`), and then change the use of `strcmp` to that.